# Can't catch event ContentLoading on WPF control toolkit WebView

Tags: c#, wpf, webview, eventhandler

I try to catch event ContentLoading as the documentation explain here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview

But I have an error at the line :

`WebviewEdge.ContentLoading += WebviewEdge_ContentLoading;`

`Error CS0123 No overload for 'WebviewEdge_ContentLoading' corresponds to the delegate 'EventHandler <WebViewControlContentLoadingEventArgs>'`

I try to change the code as :

`WebviewEdge.ContentLoading += EventHandler <WebViewControlContentLoadingEventArgs>(WebviewEdge_ContentLoading);`

But it does not work, any idea?

Here it's my xaml:

```
<Window
        x:Class="ArchiReport.ARWebview"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ArchiReport"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"             
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
        Topmost="True" 
        Width="491.25" Height="671.25" 
        Title="Connect" 
        WindowStyle="ThreeDBorderWindow" Foreground="#FFF3ECEC" 
        AutomationProperties.Name="WebConnect" 
        ShowInTaskbar="False">
    <Controls:WebView x:Name="WebviewEdge" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="640" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="483" 
        Source="myurl.html"
        ContentLoading="WebviewEdge_ContentLoading"/>
</Window>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my mistake :
I cannot add a WebView from toolkit in a Window directly, but in a UserControl, afterthat, if my class inherit from UserControl, I can handle the event.